# Can I Delete 70-persistent-net.rules?

Tags: cron, delete

Our program runs on a linux server (NAS) with 2 drives. In theory we can remove the drives from one of our clients servers and put it in another server and go. But every time I need to FIRST delete the 70-persistent-net.rules from the filesystem before placing the drives in another server. If I don't the server will not connect to network on the new machine. Can I create a cron job that deletes 70-persistent-net.rules after each reboot?

Answer (score 8):

You could, but there is probably an even better solution:

Either in `/lib/udev/rules.d` or in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, there should be a `80-persistent-net-generator.rules` file (the number at the beginning may be different). This file is responsible for creating the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file.

If the `*persistent-net-generator.rules` file is in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, your NAS server is using a pretty old version of udev; you'll need to comment out the rules in the file, but keep the file so that your modification will be kept if/when the operating system of the NAS device is patched.

If the `*persistent-net-generator.rules` file is in `/lib/udev/rules.d`, there is a simpler way to override it: just create an empty file with the *exact same filename* in `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

Any file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` will completely override any file with the same name in `/lib/udev/rules.d`... if your system uses a version of udev that has `/lib/udev/rules.d`, that is.